# Consumer only consuming messages when partition number is mentioned

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Please share the details, if you have explanation for this.

When I try to consume messages with kafka-console-consumer with topic name, data not consumed.

```
bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test1
```

But, when I mention partition number then messages are consumed.

```
bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test1 --partition 0

test1

test2

test3
```

Comment: Which Kafka version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `__consumer_offsets` topic exists, if not - is your config `offsets.topic.replication.factor` higher than the number of brokers?  which will cause `__consumer_offsets` not being created.

If this is not the case you can check kafka logs and update the post with the logs and details of your environment (Kafka version, etc).